# Accessing uploaded files outside the dist folder Angular 2 +

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload

I have a folder outside of the Dist directory called uploads. This is where all files uploaded are stored. Namely image files.

I can not figure out how to access these files without them being in the Assets directory in the dist folder. Putting them in the dist folder is not an option here.

If I upload them directly into the dist folder it will work in prod, until I need to take the site down for maintenance, then the whole dist folder will be destroyed on rebuild, and subsequently all the uploads.

If I upload to the assets folder in the src, they won't be displayed because they are not in dist. I am extremely confused and not sure what to do.

The outline of the project is to have uploads ran through a Node.js back end, stored in a local directory called uploads, and then accessed from the dist folder.

Comment: You'll need to serve them through your node backend

Comment: Can you explain a little further for me mate? not sure what you mean?

Comment: Well, either put the /uploads directory so that it's served by your HTTP server, or create an endpoint in your Node backend that reads the image file (using fs.readFile or whatever) and returns it to the front end

Comment: So it;'s impossible to access images outside of the dist assets folder in Angular?

Comment: It's impossible to access images that aren't being served by *something*. You can put them anywhere, but you will need to ensure it's being served by your HTTP server.